# After copying Joomla site, it stills redirects to the old URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, joomla

This is strange.

I have made a full copy of a Joomla 3 site, then I copied the pages into a development server, including the database.

The problem is that when I try to connect to the development server using other URL, immediately browser redirects to production URL.

I have seen in .htaccess but the redirect is not there. Maybe in the database there is a table that stores the official URL. I tried to find a table for that, but I could not find any.

Regards
Jaime

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You must have a live parameter set in joomla configuration.php file

Comment: i have this in cnfiguration.php: public $live_site = '';

Comment: I remind that there is something with a database table where the URL is stored, but I could not find a suitable table for this

Answer (score 0):

In your configuration.php, look for :

public $live_site = 'http://www.yourdomain.com';

and make sure that the value is equal to your domain name.